# Format a number 000..999

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to format a number like this:

```
000
001
002
003
004
.
.
.
010
011
.
111
.
999
```

Comment: it is unclear what are you asking

Comment: which programming language ???

Comment: @AnishJoseph I want to in Plsql orSql.

Comment: @Alexander Suppose i want to print 1 to 10. i want the output is 
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10

Comment: @user3322696 something like [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2739503983093)? Or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)?

Comment: @TechDo, I don't think your formatting saves the meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really isn't clear where your numbers are coming from. if you just want to generate a list on the fly to you can use the [connect-by syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52315):

```
select to_char(level, 'FM00')
from dual
connect by level <= 10;

01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

For 0 to 999 just change the level limit and the [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) to have the required number of digits:

```
select to_char(level - 1, 'FM000')
from dual
connect by level <= 1000;
```

Comment: @user3322696 and @Alex `lpad(level,length(your_maxmimum_number),0)`.. hope this might be generic.. (Ofcourse not decimals, as we deal like Strings and _NOT_ numbers)

Comment: Or just `SELECT TO_CHAR(n, 'FM' || lpad('0',<maxlength>,'0'))...`

Answer (score 2):

Try this pl/sql Block:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..999 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(To_CHAR(i, '009'));  
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ones.num + tens.num + hundreds.num
FROM
(SELECT 000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 10 num UNION ALL
SELECT 20 num UNION ALL
SELECT 30 num UNION ALL
SELECT 40 num UNION ALL
SELECT 50 num UNION ALL
SELECT 60 num UNION ALL
SELECT 70 num UNION ALL
SELECT 80 num UNION ALL
SELECT 90 num) ones
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
SELECT 1 num UNION ALL
SELECT 2 num UNION ALL
SELECT 3 num UNION ALL
SELECT 4 num UNION ALL
SELECT 5 num UNION ALL
SELECT 6 num UNION ALL
SELECT 7 num UNION ALL
SELECT 8 num UNION ALL
SELECT 9 num) tens
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
SELECT 100 num UNION ALL
SELECT 200 num UNION ALL
SELECT 300 num UNION ALL
SELECT 400 num UNION ALL
SELECT 500 num UNION ALL
SELECT 600 num UNION ALL
SELECT 700 num UNION ALL
SELECT 800 num UNION ALL
SELECT 900 num) hundreds;
```

Comment: This won't work in Oracle as written; all of the sub-selects need to be selecting from something, like `from dual`. Seems like quite a lot of work though. It also doesn't apply the formatting the OP asked for.

Comment: The OP said 'in Plsql orSql' but it's tagged for Oracle, so an answer that doesn't work in Oracle's plain SQL isn't really helpful. SQL doesn't mean SQL Server.